# How to make POST request with JSON body using web-sys in WebAssembly?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, yew, web-sys

How to create POST request with JSON body using web-sys in WebAssembly?

This example below showing how to make GET request, I need to change **opts.method("GET");** to **opts.method("POST");** but how can i pass a JSON body to the reqeuest.

```
    let mut opts = RequestInit::new();
    opts.method("GET");
    opts.credentials(web_sys::RequestCredentials::Include);
    
    let request = Request::new_with_str_and_init(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books",
         &opts
    ).unwrap();
    
    match web_sys::window() {
        Some(window) => {
            let _res = JsFuture::from(window.fetch_with_request(&request))
                .await
                .map(|err| web_sys::console::log_1(&format!("{:?}", err)
                .into()));
        },
        None => web_sys::console::log_1(&format!("window is none").into()),
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the body using [`RequestInit::body()`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.RequestInit.html#method.body) and the required headers using [`Headers::set`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.Headers.html#method.set). You have to pass an `Option<JsValue>` to `RequestInit::body()`. To pass a string, you can do:

```rust
let mut opts = RequestInit::new();
opts.method("POST");
opts.body(Some(wasm_bindgen::JsValue::from_str("[1, 2, 3]")));
opts.credentials(web_sys::RequestCredentials::Include);
    
let request = Request::new_with_str_and_init(
    "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books",
    &opts
).unwrap();

request.headers().set("content-type", "application/json");

// send the request
```

To send a more complex object, you can use serde with [`JsValue::from_serde`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/struct.JsValue.html#method.from_serde).

Comment: would be great if you could share the sending part...seems very important to me.